# Getting away from a customized Magento 1.4 installation - Magento 1.6, OpenCart, or others?

Tags: ecommerce, magento

I'm dealing with a Magento 1.4.0.0 Community Edition installation with various undocumented changes to the core (mostly integration with an ERP system), an outdated Sweet Tooth Points & Rewards module and some custom payment providers. It also doubles as a mediocre blogging/CMS system. It has one store each for 3 different languages, with about 40 product categories for a few hundred products.

The client is planning to redesign the site, and is considering upgrading to Magento 1.6 or 1.7 if it has improved from 1.4.

The client is also open to other e-commerce systems. I've looked at OpenCart and it seems to be quite developer friendly with a fairly simple structure. I found some complaints regarding its performance when the shop has thousands of categories or products, but this is not an issue with the current number of products my client has. It seems to be solid ground for easy customization to bring the rewards system and ERP integration over.

What should the client upgrade to in this case, are the newer versions of Magento genuinely better or should I consider another system entirely?

Comment: Can anyone explain the downvote please?

Comment: It's a very long way of asking what eCommerce site/CMS should I use (I've edited for brevity). I'd go look at some of the better eCommerce WordPress or drupal plugins since they seem to be less buggy and more frequently updated than Magneto.

Comment: If it meets your needs, either Magento and OpenCart are great platforms. But if they modify the core, then they're just gonna shoot themselves in the foot regardless of which platform they use. There's no reason to modify the core unless you need to apply a temporary patch to the core while you wait for an official update. Magento comes with a very robust plugin architecture and API that, while not well-documented, can be used to customize Magento pretty much any way you want, including integrating it with an ERP system.

Comment: The down- and close votes are mine. The enormous now-removed "rant" section served no apparent purpose beyond venting, and to be honest I still can't find much of a concrete question. It mostly seems to me you hate your current setup and want other people to evaluate the more recent version(s) for you, as well as several modules/compatibility, *plus* unspecified hacks to core that relate to an external application. (In retrospect, I should've voted "too localized.") Whether to potentially switch to OpenCart is an entire question unto itself, considering the presumed need to match features.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, guys. I was really frustrated with Magento when I posted this question, it does look silly now looking in retrospect. I should be deciding on my own.